# AngularJS Ionic using ng-model between two controllers

Tags: angularjs, mvvm, angularjs-ng-model

Well, try to update my code to use both .value and .factory to clean and optimize my App...
Now, my services.js looks like :

```
// Définition des données lues par le scan du code barre
.value("ScanDatas",{
    collectedDatas: {}
})

// Service de scan des codes-barre : dépend de scanDatas
.factory("ScanService", ["ScanDatas", function (ScanDatas) {
    var scan = {};

    scan.scanBarCode = function(){
        var scanner = cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner; // Récupère le scanner

        // Exécute le scan proprement dit
        scanner.scan(
            function(result){
                alert("Lecture du code-barre\n" +
                    "Résultat : " + result.text + "\n" +
                    "Format : " + result.format + "\n" +
                    "Annulation : " + result.cancelled
                );
                ScanDatas.collectedDatas.text = result.text;
                ScanDatas.collectedDatas.format = result.format;
                ScanDatas.collectedDatas.annulation = result.cancelled;

            }, function(error){
                ScanDatas.collectedDatas.error = error;
            }
        )
    }
    return scan;
}])
```

Edit my controller to call service and scan works well when i click on the button :

```
    .controller("ScanCtrl", ["$scope", "$ionicPopup", "$timeout", "ScanDatas", "ScanService", function ($scope,$ionicPopup,$timeout,ScanDatas,ScanService){
    $scope.add = {}; // Initialise l'objet pour la récupération des données


    $scope.scanBarCode = function(){
        var scanResult = ScanService.scanBarCode();
        console.log("Données reçues : " + ScanDatas.collectedDatas.text);
        $scope.add.ean = ScanDatas.collectedDatas.text;
    }
}])
```

But, in the wiew, the ng-model add.ean keep desesperatly empty... Not sure to understand the way the .value() works with view and controllers...

Thx to @Claie

I'm a beginner with AngularJS and Ionic and have a problem with MVVM.
Have the following view :

```
<ion-view title="Ajouter" id="page2" class=" ">
<ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
    <button id="ajouter-button3" class=" button button-positive  button-block " ng-controller="ScanCtrl" ng-click="scanBarCode()">Scanner</button>
    <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 13px;"></div>
    <form id="ajouter-form1" class="list ">
        <label class="item item-select " id="ajouter-select1" name="stockage">
            <span class="input-label">Stockage</span>
            <select id="add-storage-area" class="form-control" required="required" data-ng-options="storageArea.id as storageArea.libelle for storageArea in storageAreas" ng-model="form.storageArea"></select>
        </label>

        <label class="item item-input " id="add-ean" name="ean">
            <span class="input-label">EAN</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Code EAN" name="add.ean" ng-model="add.ean">
        </label>
...
```

The controller for the "scanCtrl" is the following :

```
  .controller('ScanCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope,$ionicPopup,$timeout) {
    var scanner = cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner; // Récupère le scanner
    $scope.scanBarCode = function(){
        scanner.scan(
            function(result){
                alert("Lecture du code-barre\n" +
                    "Résultat : " + result.text + "\n" +
                    "Format : " + result.format + "\n" +
                    "Annulation : " + result.cancelled
                );
                $scope.add.ean = result.text;
            }, function(error){
                //alert("Le scan a échoué : " + error);
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: "Erreur",
                    template: "Une erreur est survenue lors de la lecture du code-barre"
                }).then(function(res){
                    // Effacer les données du formulaire ?
                });
            }
        )
    }
}])
```

And correctly get the EAN barcode, but :

```
$scope.add.ean = result.text;
```

Doesn't work, no value placed in the related input...

Sure it's a beginner mistake but...

Thx...

Comment: adding a controller for a single button doesn't feel like a very efficient process; this kind of thing is normally better handled by a directive.  If you *must* do this, however, you should use a service to hold the data shared between controllers.  if you can't use a service, then you might, as a last resort, be able to use `$parent`.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a good idea... Will work in this way... Have to use this method in different parts of my app so i think it's a better way to use a service

Comment: Hi @Claies use factory and value to get barcode infos... But even if reading the barcode works well, still can't get datas in my controller...
Keep work in this way, thx...

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want `$rootScope`? `$rootScope` is global scope that can hold values between controllers, filters, directives and so on

Comment: `$rootScope` would work, but using `$rootScope` is an anti-pattern, which is why I did not recommend it in my comment regarding alternatives.  I would put `$rootScope` below `$parent` in ranking of options to solve the issue here.

Comment: Use $rootScope and it works... Thx... But will try to use a service to be abble to use the scanning method in different parts of the app...